# Smartest way to get unix time here and now

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, unix-timestamp

I need to have a local unix timestamp and have ended up with this terrible long expression:

```
NSTimeInterval unixTimeHereAndNow = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]+[[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
```

It works, but really? Isn't it any way to write it shorter? And secondly, will it always be accurate?

Comment: ok, just try: 
`NSDate.date.timeIntervalSince1970+NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone.secondsFromGMT`

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the length of that. It's expressive.

Comment: If you use this a lot and want it more readable, add a category on NSDate and make your own method so you can just write '[[NSDate date] unixTimestamp]'

Comment: Write a function.  You can use a plain old C function that can be called from anywhere if you wish, or a class method if the C function scares you.

Comment: Or just shove the above into a C macro.